# TFX root in TFX taxi example

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

What does the `_tfx_root` in the Chicago taxi example refer to and why is it needed?

I'm talking about this line: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline/taxi_pipeline_simple.py#L54

The metadata end pipelines end up in ~/tfx but without having a local copy of the tfx git repo it does not run in Airflow (locally).

The metadata directory is created when running `airflow initdb`, after you've manually copied the pipeline Python file to `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/blabla` directory. It would be nice to be able to configure the location of `~/tfx` though. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

```
code:- _tfx_root = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'tfx');
```

It is used to define **relative path** to the directory called **'tfx'** which is created at home directory(if it doesn't exist) of logged in user. in which HOME is an environment variable.

```
code:- _pipeline_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'pipelines');
```

use relative path to create/append child directory **"pipelines"** to **tfx_root** path.

```
code:- _metadata_db_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'metadata');
```

use relative path to create/append child directory **"metadata"** to **tfx_root** path.

```
code:- _log_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'logs');
```

use relative path to create/append child directory **"logs"** to **tfx_root** path.

Answer (score 1):

It is the path of the data directory. This variable is only used to build the path of the pipeline, metadata and root directories.

```
_tfx_root = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'tfx');        // Create location ~/tfx
_pipeline_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'pipelines');      // Join ~/tfx/pipelines/
_metadata_db_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'metadata');    // Join ~/tfx/metadata/
_log_root = os.path.join(_tfx_root, 'logs');                // Join ~/tfx/logs/
```

Just modify `_tfx_root` to change the location of `~/tfx`. If you want the location to be `C:/temp/tfx`. Use this for example.

```
_tfx_root = 'C:/temp/tfx/';
```

Comment: But `_tfx_root` needs to be a `git clone` of the TFX repo. If it's just an empty directory with metadata and pipelines in it, it does not run. So it's more than just a location on the file system.

Comment: According to the comment above `_tfx_root`. This example assumes all of the chicago taxi example code and metadata library is **relative to $HOME**. However you can **store** these files **anywhere** on your local filesystem.

Comment: What's the point of creating a virtual environment then? If all the required files are in `$HOME/tfx`, why do I have to install the dependencies too? https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline

Comment: Instead of install dependencies you can clone TFX into `C:/Program Files/TFX` and setting the TFX_DIR environment variable on your projects.

Comment: But why would you want to depend on a clone of a repo instead of the library itself? I may be missing something but it seems odd that I have to clone the TFX repo to run it locally with Airflow when I already have to copy the pipelines, data, model file to Airflow, and create a virtualenv.

Comment: I've no idea. I'm going to try locally.